# webpage not displaying properly when window size is reduced

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am working on a project  (mobile store) im my college.The products on the below link contain 8 mobiles.I can see 8 mobiles when the windows is maximized and only 6 when the windows size is reduced. Why is that?

Refer Link:[myproject](http://estoreproj.xyz/apple.aspx)

I used a template from w3layouts.com,which is here if anyone needs it-[mobileshop layout](https://w3layouts.com/mobile-store-e-commerce-shopping-cart-mobile-website-template/)

I want the page to show 8 mobiles even when minimized. What am i doing wrong?I'm just starting to learn so please be gentle.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The solution from @AdamMcquiff should do what you need @Melwin. It's also worth considering that grouping CSS classes up on your grid `<div>` elements can get you into some trouble in future. It could be a good idea to split them out so you have a `<div class='products-info">` contained within the `<div class="grid_1_of_4 images_1_of_4">`. Doing it that way can prevent padding or margin issues with your grid.

Comment: Thanks @Monkeybruiser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS rule `.images_1_of_4:last-child` in your `max-width: 1024` media query is hiding the last element of each row:

```
.images_1_of_4:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Remove this style and the element will reappear.

You will need to rethink your grid system for mobile to make the columns appear correctly.

Comment: Great! Would you be able to approve my answer?

Comment: Done----------☺